# Xamarin Forms - what control to use to achieve...?

Tags: xamarin.forms

This will probably be a simple question to answer.

Collection of X where X has a property that's another collection.  For example each object represents a day which has a collection property that represents entries for that day.  So I want it to iterate through each day, and for each day I want it to iterate through each of the day's entries.  So you would have the following on screen:

**Tuesday 15th January**

**Entry 1**
 Entry 1's Description
 
 Horizontal Image gallery scroll (one row)

**Entry 2**
 Entry 2's Description
 Horizontal Image gallery scroll (one row)

**Wednesday 16th January**

**Entry 1**
 Entry 1's Description
 Horizontal Image gallery scroll (one row)

**Entry 2**
 Entry 2's Description
 Horizontal Image gallery scroll (one row)

**Entry 3**
 Entry 3's Description
 Horizontal Image gallery scroll (one row)

Straight forward... I've managed to get the above (minus the image gallery) using a ListView (Grouped), however I don't want each Day / Day Entry to be clickable. Only thing that should be clickable are the images to display they full screen.

I've used the RepeaterView in Labs, however it doesn't seem to allow Grouping nor nested collections...

Any pointers would be much appreciated. I know what I want to do, I know how I would do it in other platforms (non mobile), but don't know how to do it in this new Xamarin Forms world...

Answer (score 1):

You might want yo use **[ListView](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#grouping)**. It allows to grouping data. You can also [customize the cells](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Customizing_the_Appearance_of_a_Cell).

Answer (score 0):

This is a listview for the main view. And use a stack layout for the cells.
Set the Orientation to Vertical.

```
   return new ViewCell
   {
        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
```